# wired or bus troubleshooting

Tags: mosfet, bus

I have designed a photo-sensing array that consists of phototransistors (RPM075PTT86) and n-channel fets (see circuit below) duplicated 25 times. This is a very simple circuit that works OK, but I have come to realize that it is very hard to locate a defective fet among those connected to the common 'wired or' bus. The original circuit did not have the 10 ohm resistors, making it tough to identify a shorted or defective fet. Note that the 25 sensors are split into two groups to avoid leakage problems. I put the 10 ohm resistor in as a 'current sense' in the hopes that a shorted fet will be close to ground at the drain, while normal ones will be a little higher in voltage (Id x 10). In this circuit Vcc is 5V. I have not implemented this but I plan to in the next spin. The question is, given the bus array, what's the best way to locate a bad transistor? Some possible approaches:
1. Shine a light on the array (all transistors off). If the bus is low short it to 5VDC and the shorted transistor(s) will smoke and burn, maybe
2. Use a sensitive ohm-meter to find the current path- none of my meters are sensitive enough, you would need a nano-ohmmeter
3. Use the method of the drain resistor to detect current, probably the most effective

Is there a better way? Can the circuit be improved?
[image]

Comment: Hmm.. two points. 1) mosfet can fail short or open. 2) adding more components to what is already a minimal circuit significantly increases chance of a failure.

Comment: What is your Vlo max tolerance?

Comment: The bus is connected to a 74AHC2G00 dual nand device. VIh is about 3.8V across temp, VIl is about 1.6V. BSS123 off leakage is <10nA. I calculate that when 'on', the drop across the 10 ohms is about .22V [(5/230)*10]. So the thresholds look OK. I appreciate that adding the resistors will theoretically increase failure rate, but the benefit of being able to make repairs easy outweighs the negatives. Not sure I ever had a resistor fail, but there are a lot more solder joints.

Comment: Forgot to say, open fets are no problem, just look for >1.7V on the gate (threshold), drain will not pull down when light is shone on the sensor.

Answer (score 0):

The 10R resistor should be enough. Any FET still on will present about 20mV across it, compared to zero on the others.

You may want to consider running the Vcc for the top of the 56Ks together and putting then through a jumper so you can ground all the gates rather than using a light though.